# How to remove example(label) for map backgroud mapbox in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, mapbox

I made sample project for map MapBox its done but when i am terrain map type set its show perfectly but issue is example(label) shown. How can i remove for this issue? Help me thanks in advance.

I show issue for this image.

[image]

Comment: Its map perfectly display but example text show multiple times this issue for i need to remove it....!!!!

Comment: https://www.mapbox.com/help/remove-examples-watermark/

Comment: Thanks for suggest link for that link and i would created again new project but did not getting solution...!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library is open source. Go in and remove the label by editing the source code. There is not a public API for this.